# Django 2 form is_valid is not working even on valid form data

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-2.0, django-validation

I'm working on a very simple form to post data in Django(2) but always getting the form as invalid because the `form.is_valid()` not getting called.

Here's what I have so far:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='notingroup')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group
```

**From `forms.py`:**

```
class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = ('group', 'email')
```

**From `views.py`:**

```
def group_name(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST['email'])
        group_form = UserGroupForm(request.POST)
        print(group_form)
        if group_form.is_valid():
            ug_obj = UserGroup()
            ug_obj.group = group_form.cleaned_data['group']
            ug_obj.email = group_form.cleaned_data['email']
            ug_obj.save()
            return JsonResponse({"message": 'Got it inside valid'})

        else:
            error = 'Something went wrong'
            print(error)

        return JsonResponse({"message": 'an error occurs!'})
```

**From `html template`:**

```
<form method="post" id="gitForm" action="javascript:call_my_form()">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label>Groupname: </label>
                <input id="user_email" type="text" value="{{ user.email }}" hidden>
                <input id="input" type="text" class="">
                <input type="submit" value="Mehet" class="btn btn-primary">
       <div id="error" style="color:red"></div>
</form>
```

**From `javasctip function for Ajax`:**

```
function call_my_form() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#gitForm', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($('#input').val());
        console.log($('#user_email').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/groupname',
            data: {
                group: $('#input').val(),
                email: $('#user_email').val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function (jsonResponse) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsonResponse.message;

            }
        }).done(function (jsonResponse) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsonResponse.message;
        })
    });
}
```

I'm getting the correct data into the view but still the `form.is_valid()` not get called,

Here's the output:

> **********@mail.com 
>   `<tr><th><label
>   for="id_group">Group:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="group"
>   value="scsacas" maxlength="250" required id="id_group"></td></tr>
>   <tr><th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th><td><ul
>   class="errorlist"><li>User group with this Email already
>   exists.</li></ul><input type="email" name="email"
>   value="abdul12391@gmail.com" maxlength="254" required
>   id="id_email"></td></tr>`
>
> Something went wrong [18/Jul/2019 09:47:47]
>   "POST /groupname HTTP/1.1" 200 31

Comment: You should print `group_form.errors` in your else block to see exactly what the problem is. Even better, return it in your JsonResponse

Comment: Since the email is the primary key, it is unique, and you thus used the *same* email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in your output: `User group with this Email already exists.`

So you're trying to submit an email that already exists. That's why your `form.is_valid()` isn't being called.